# Deleting non empty folder C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete non empty folder using `Directory.Delete(dirName,true);`
and getting exception {"Access to the path 'fit' is denied."}
Any idea why? how to solve?
Thanks,
Tal

Comment: You might have a process running an executable file from this folder. Or you may have this folder open in your Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the folder (right click, properties).  Verify the user has access to delete that folder.  If no, add that permission.  If yes, then download and run ProcExp [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), then click on the binoculars icon and search for the folder name to see if any process is holding a handle on that directory or a file under its path.  If so, then either close the app that has the handle or force close the handle from ProcExp.